# How to show screenshot instant after uploading a image in a form with Ajax, jQuery and PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, screenshot

I have a form HTML and users can upload a image to make screenshot to preview.

```
<form id="myForm" action="message.php" method="post"> 
    Screenshot: <div class="show_image"></div> <br />
    <input type="file" name="name" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> <br />
</form>
```

I also refer some articles on Internet but I don't know the way to do it. Can you give me some solutions or ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: you can use an uploader script  which could have a lot of other features,  or you could make something easier,  make the form target to a hidden iframe, make sure the enctype of the form is multipart, then upon upload finish the resulting page in the iframe, make it update the div show_image in parent via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

what is the plugin you are using? Almost the AJAX_UPLOAD plugins have the call-back function to show the image after uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have not used any plugins yet. I will try some ajax upload plugins which you mention.